# A question about dense sets

Tags: co.combinatorics, mg.metric-geometry, discrete-geometry

Suppose that $A$ is a given subset of $I=[0,1],\ $ and
$ \left\{ x_j = \frac{j}{m} \right\}_{j=0}^{m}\ $ is the $m$-partition of $I$, and $\nu(m)$ is the number of
$\ [x_{i-1},x_{i}]\ $ such that $\ [x_{i-1},x_{i}]\cap A \neq \emptyset\ $ for intervals $\ [x_{i-1},x_{i}]\ $ belonging to the $m$-partition. Also assume that $M>0$ is such that

$$ \forall_{m>M}\quad \nu(m) \ge \ln(m) $$

Does it follow that $A$ is dense on some open non-empty subinterval of $I$?

> ***Remark*** (editorial by wlod): the rest of the post is unclear to editor wlod. Once the things get clear, this remark should be removed. ### This remark is here to avoid a prolonged (if momentary) discussion in comments. ### Also, Wlod followed by Andreas have provided counter-examples, and -- to make it better -- they need not the complication of constant $M$. Wlod stated the result for general functions $f$ in place of $\ f:=\ln$. Then Andreas had it for a wider class of functions $f$ (but Wlod's proof handles it too).

An example:

Let $A = \{\frac{1}{j}\}_{j=1}^{\infty}$. By some calculation we can get the value of $n$:
$$1,7,23,70,211,649,$$
when $m$ is $1,10,100,1000,10000,100000$,respectively.

Notes: I want to emphasize that you cannot construct $A$ with $m$ related to the precondition, because $m$ is given and changing to $\infty$ after $A$ has been supposed. Even if you want to construct $A$ with some variables, please notice that when $A$ is constructed, your variables are fixed and cannot follow the change of $m$.

Comment: What if you construct the set $A$ as follows?  For each $m$, pick just enough points as close to 0 as possible so that the desired inequality holds for $m$.  Then I think for every interval $(a,b)$, where $a>0$, $A \cap (a,b)$ is finite.

Comment: This is basically what the answer below does.

Comment: @MonroeEskew. $m$ is given and changes after $A$ has been constructed. You cannot do anything with the constructed $A$ while $m$ changes. It's like you pick up a real number first, and you can find certain real numbers greater than the number you pick up. But you cannot find certain real numbers greater than an arbitrary real number.

Comment: $A$ is a countably infinite set.  I construct it once.

Comment: @MonroeEskew Please give me the $\sup$ of $A$ you have constructed.

Comment: Can OP provide a formal formulation, using $\ \forall\ $ and $\ \exists\ $, to make the question clearer to some of us (to me)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll construct an $A$ that satisfies the conditions of the question but is not dense in any interval. I'll use the notation in the question and abbreviate the $i$-th interval of the $m$-th partition as $J(m,i)$. There are two requirements that I need to satisfy:

(1) For every $m$, $A$ contains points from at least $\ln m$ of the $m$ intervals $J(m,i)$.

(2) For all $m$ and all $i$, $J(m,i)$ has a nontrivial subinterval $K(m,i)$ disjoint from $A$.

Note that requirement (2) ensures that $A$ is not dense in any nontrivial interval, because any such interval includes $J(m,i)$ for some $m$ and some $i$.

I'll build $A$ by an inductive process. At step number $m$, I'll choose some finitely many points to put into $A$ in order to satisfy (1) for the current $m$, and I'll choose the $m$ subintervals $K(m,i)$ to satisfy (2) for the current $m$ and all $i\leq m$. Of course I need to make sure that the points I put into $A$ for the sake of (1) are not in any previously chosen excluded interval $K$ and that the intervals $K$ that I exclude for the sake of (2) don't contain any of the points previously put into $A$.

Fix, for the rest of the construction, a sequence of positive real numbers $r(m)$ small enough so that $\sum_{m=1}^\infty mr(m)<\frac12$. The subintervals $K(m,i)$ chosen at step $m$ will each have length $\leq r(m)$.

Now here's how to do step $m$. The previous steps have put (altogether) finitely many points into $A$. So I can choose, inside each of the $m$ intervals $J(m,i)$, a subinterval containing none of the points already put into $A$. Shrinking those subintervals if necessary, I can arrange that each has length $\leq r(m)$. Take those shrunken subintervals as $K(m,i)$.

What is the total length of all the intervals $K(q,i)$ chosen so far, i.e., with $q\leq m$ and $i\leq q$?  Well, at step $q$, we chose $q$ intervals of length at most $r(q)$, so the total length is at most $\sum_{q=1}^m q\cdot r(q)$, which is less than $\frac12$ by our choice of the $r$ sequence. So those intervals, though they might intersect all of the current $J(m,i)$'s, cannot completely cover more than $\frac m2$ of them. In each of the $J(m,i)$ that are not completely covered, which is at least $\frac m2$ of them, we can choose a point and put it into $A$. Do so; this satisfies requirement (1) with room to spare ($\lceil\frac m2\rceil$ instead of $\ln m$). This completes the construction of the counterexample.

Remark: The "room to spare" that I pointed out at the end of the construction can be amplified. For any fixed $\epsilon$, we can get $A$ to meet all but $\epsilon m$ of the intervals $J(m,i)$ in the $m$-th partition. Just choose the $r(m)$'s a little smaller.1

Comment: At the beginning of your answer, could you reformulate the OP's question in a formal way (using nothing but $\ \forall\, $ and $\ \exists\ $, etc. ? I don't find the present formulation of the OP's question clear.

Comment: @WlodAA I understood the problem to be proving or refuting the statement: If a subset $A$ of the unit interval has the property that, for each $m$, at least $\ln m$ of the $m$ intervals $[\frac{i-1}m,\frac im]$ contain points from $A$, then $A$ must be dense in some nontrivial subinterval.

Comment: Isn't my simple answer providing a counter-example?

Comment: Thus, say, $\ J(m\ i):=\left[\frac{i-1}m;\frac im\right]$ ?

Comment: And, say, $\ \emptyset\ne K(m\ i):=(a_{m\ i};b_{m\ i})\subset J(m\ i)\ $ for certain $\ a_{m\ i}\ $ and $\ b_{m\ i}\ $ (where $\ a_{m\ i}<b_{m\ i})\ $) ?

Comment: @WlodAA I have changed the way to state my question by your suggestion. Now the question statement is using the form similar to $\varepsilon$-$\delta$ of the definition of limit.

Comment: @WlodAA I think I misunderstood your answer originally. It now looks correct to me (assuming, of course, that the question means what I think it means). So the only advantage in my more complicated answer is that it works even for $f(m)=(1-\varepsilon)m$ rather than $o(m)$.

Comment: @AndreasBlass, $\ (1-\epsilon)\cdot m\ $ is nice! (However, my proof works also for this tougher case too).

Answer (score 3):

Let the number of the $m$-th partition intervals which intersect $\ A\ $ be $\ \ge f(m).\ $ Then

**Theorem**  There exists $\ A\ $ which is not dense in any non-trivial interval whenever

$$ \lim_{m=\infty} \frac {f(m)}m\ =\ 0 $$

**Proof**  The required $\ A\ $ can be given as follows:

$$ A\ :=\\
\ \left\{ \frac {2\cdot k-1}{2\cdot m}:
         \ m\in\Bbb N\ \ \text{and}
         \ \ k\in\Bbb Z\ \ \text{and}\ \ 0<k\le f(m)\,\right\} $$

**End of Proof**

Comment: By “it is possible” you mean that a counterexample exists, whereas the answer asked “is it possible to prove”. Could you edit so as to remove this confusion? (Generally speaking, it's best to avoid “yes” or “or” or variants thereupon.)

Comment: Have you noted that $A$ has been supposed at the beginning of the question? This indicates $A$ does not depend on variables given behind, like $m$ and $n$.

Comment: @Gro-Tsen, I hope that I followed your observation and suggestion.

Comment: If you want to unrelate your $m$ to the $m$ in the precondition, you have to take the limit for the $m$ in your theorem. But this will render your $A=\{0\}$.

Comment: @WlodAA Let's get this straight. We can get $\sup A = \frac{2f(m)-1}{2m}$ from your constructed $A$. If the limit is taken, $\sup A = 0$ so that $A = \{0\}$ or $A=\emptyset$.

Comment: OP, please make the formulation of your Question **straight**. Your comments here, under my question, are **not straight** at all. If you still stand by them then, please, clarify them in a straightforward manner - please, make things **explicit**.

Comment: @Watheophy, have you noted that given function $\ f\ $ (e.g. $\ f:=\log),\ $ my $\ A\ $ is constant, it doesn't depend on any variables like $\ n\ $ or $\ m$?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107662/discussion-between-watheophy-and-wlod-aa).